# Ubuntu 13.10 end of support

Tags: 13.10, security, support

13.10 ends support today, I want to do a clean install of 14.04.1,but it arrives next week,is it highly risk to wait fot 14.04.1 one week with 13.10 no supported? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, I personally only do my updates once a week, so it won't really make a difference. Ubuntu, as a rule, is pretty secure security wise.